# How to implement twitter auth login in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla2.5

Hey guys i am working on joomla 2.5 and i want to any twitter user can login in his twitter account on my site.

Please help for implement twitter auth login in my login page in joomla 2.5

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of OpenId or OAuth authentication systems. This helps you in authenticating not just Twitter but Google, Yahoo etc.

There is a Drupal Extension for this: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-cloud-based/20465

Try it, its easy!